# Apache or Varnish reverse proxy to subfolder

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, varnish

I have a domain, site.example.com and I would like to reverse-proxy a web app in site2.example.com/subfolder. Users should access that app by using site.example.com/subfolder. Is it possible? I would like to use Apache or even better varnish (without hitting Apache) to do the redirect.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use Apache unless there you have a high traffic site. This can be done using [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) with [ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) and [ProxyPassReverse](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse).

It will end up being something like on the site.example.com server:

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On
ProxyPass /subfolder http://site2.example.com/subfolder
ProxyPassReverse /subfolder http://site2.example.com/subfolder
```